# React Hook "useState" cannot be called at the top level

Tags: react-hooks

I am a beginner in react. I'm trying to send values of my database from one file to another using react-hooks, and getting the following error can anyone help me with this?

Line 5:41:   React Hook "useState" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function   react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
Code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

import Axios from "axios";

const [collegeList, setcollegeList]=useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/get").then((response)=>{
        setcollegeList(response.data);
    });
}, []);

CollegeList = collegeList;
export default CollegeList;
```

Answer (score 3):

You must use react hooks in react components. There're two ways i can recommend to you to fix this.

first) Doing it in your component

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

function CollegeListComponent() {
const [collegeList, setcollegeList]=useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/get").then((response)=>{
        setcollegeList(response.data);
    });
}, []);

return "YOUR VIEW ELEMENTS"
```

second) Use it as react hook

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

// making a custom react hook like this
function useCollegeList() {
   const [collegeList, setcollegeList]=useState([]);

   useEffect(()=>{
       Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/get").then((response)=>{
           setcollegeList(response.data);
       });
   }, []);

return { collegeList }
```

and then you can import useCollegeList in your component to use it

Comment: Sorry this is not working can you give me detailed explanation. Here, I'm adding code of after doing modifications you suggested.    function useCollegeList(){
    const [collegeList, setcollegeList]=useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/get").then((response)=>{
            setcollegeList(response.data);
        });
    }, []);

    return {collegeList};
}
export default useCollegeList;

Comment: sure i forgot to add } at the last and exporting cuz i thought that was enough to understand what i meant to describe. sorry for missing details

Comment: I understood what you said and I already added },exporting line but it is still not working. Can't I export the array 'collegeList' instead of exporting function 'useCollegeList'.